setting default values in Python Protobuf fields
I am writing some python test routines with protobuf acting as the communication medium with a firmware module.  I keep tripping over an issue.  I receive a response from a module expecting a value in a protobuf field and it's empty.  I know that protobuf skips over fields that have the default value in the message, but it would be nice to be able to count on that field to be set in the program itself.
Example:
I have a protobuf field:
  ReturnCode returnCode = 11;

On normal conditions, the return code is 0, which skips the field in the message.  But I want to have something in my python code like:
       response = await common.mkRequest(study_pb2.STUDY_LIST, study_list_cmd)
       resp = await common.decodePacket(response.resp)
       assert resp.returnCode==0

Here, resp contains the decoded protobuf message that would contain returnCode.  But when returnCode is the default 0, it is undefined.
Is there any way to set (after decode) or preset (before the decode) the default values for a message so I don't have to use something like:
getattr(resp, 'returnCode', study_pb2.EOK), resp.study

This gives the default value for returnCode, but I would like to do this for the entire message without having to explicitly coding this for each field.

Your question is unclear and I'm unsure which Python libraries you're using. Default values are omitted from the on-the-wire (binary) message but are present|retained otherwise. Using Google's Protobuf library for Python (protobuf) and attempting to repro your Protobuf source using a message (X) with a single field int32 return_code, I'm able to x=study_pb2.X() then assert x.return_code==0 without issue.

Sorry it's unclear.  I tried to piece together examples from our test scripts that run several layers deep.
I realize the on-the-wire message does not contain default values.The actual messages go over BLE or USB, and the protobuf messages are layered in other protobuf messages.  In this case I've taken the innermost message and run it through study_pb2.StudyList().ParseFromString(msgString).  The resulting object only contains non-default fields.
The protobuf for Python I'm using is:
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: protobuf
Version: 4.21.9
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
